# Etwas einstellen aus/von einer Position

Tags: preposition, technical-terminology

If I want to say that something can be set from a certain position (as in the  setting mechanism is reachable from a certain position), do I use

> etw. einstellen aus einer Position

or

> etw. einstellen von einer Position

Example:

Der Winkel ist einfach einstellbar von/aus der Position des Fahrers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The funny answer here is: both are possible (with **von** being a little better than **aus**), but a combination of both is even better.

> Der Winkel ist **von** der Position des Fahrers **aus** einfach einstellbar

The reason is: You describe that there is a position with **von**,
and at the same time you describe that there is a movement or action originating in the position of the driver by using **aus**.

My example can be seen as a short form for:

> Der Winkel ist von der Position des Fahrers **ausgehend** einfach einstellbar

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

> Der Winkel ist vom Fahrersitz aus einstellbar.

I would not focus on the driver (as the driver doesn’t need to be in the requested position all the time, or someone not being the driver might have to adjust it from the driver’s seat as well, e.g. a mechanic) but on the position.

> von einer Position aus einstellbar/bedienbar sein